# Does BigQuery support SubQueries?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In my SQL FROM clause, I want to use a dynamically created table via a subquery:

```
Select A.Field1,B.Field2
FROM TableA as A, (select Field1,Field2 from TableB) B
Where A.Field1 = B.Field1
```

Does BigQuery support this?

Comment: Did you try running it and checking what the outcome is?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a subquery for this:

```
Select A.Field1,B.Field2
FROM TableA as A join
     TableB as B
     on A.Field1 = B.Field1;
```

But yes, according to the [reference manual](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference), BigQuery does support subqueries.

Comment: Notice that you can use the usual types of joins: inner, left, right, outer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, I remember doing something like

```
SELECT a ,b
FROM Tablea
WHERE a not IN (SELECT a FROM Tableb)
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's formally fix your query (assuming you are using BigQuery Legacy SQL)
Please note that in Legacy SQL comma is used not as JOIN but rather as UNION ALL

So you query, to work, should look like below

```
SELECT A.Field1, B.Field2
FROM TableA AS A 
JOIN (SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM TableB) AS B
ON A.Field1 = B.Field1
```

Of course in your particular example you don’t need subselect, but I think it is just simplified example so I am not going this direction and other answers already pointed to this anyway

Finally, about subqueries in BigQuery
BigQuery Legacy SQL supports very limited use of Subqueries - know as `table subquery` - in FROM and FLATTEN and semi- or anti-semi-JOIN (with only one field)
You can find details here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference

From the other hand BigQuery Standard SQL provides reach support for Subqueries - for table subqueries as well as expression subqueries
You can see more here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/query-syntax#subqueries
Note: BigQuery Standard SQL version is in Alpha yet