# SQL GROUP BY a result

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I’m struggling with a SQL query.

The task I want to accomplish is to count how many users used the app 5 days, how many users 4 days etc.

I want a table like this:

```
days | user_count
---- | ---
   5 | 2
   4 | 2
   2 | 1
   1 | 1
```

What I have is a logfile with events, event_date and user_id. So what I managed to query was this:

```
SELECT 
  user_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT event_date) AS days
FROM
  mytable
GROUP BY user_id
```

this is the resulting table.

```
user_id | days
------- | ----
      a | 5
      b | 5
      c | 4
      d | 4
      e | 2
      f | 1
```

But I need a table like shown above (days, user_count)

QUESTION: How can I get the result with **one** query?

I wish I would take the result and group it again by days. But this does not work in one query (I of cause can’t use ORDER BY with accumulated columns).

I’m using the WebUI of Google BigQuery and it seems that temporary tables are not easy to do. So I was thinking of combining two queries but my skills in SQL are limited. Reading about UNION, WHERE IN or subqueries, correlated queries did not bring me any further.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#subqueries why can't you nest the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way would be to nest queries. (creating a in memory table or inline view however you want to look at it)

```
SELECT count(User_ID) cnt, days
FROM (SELECT user_id
           , COUNT(DISTINCT event_date) AS days
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY user_id) z
GROUP BY days
ORDER BY Days Desc
```

Reference: [Does BigQuery support SubQueries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166150/does-bigquery-support-subqueries)

I'm looking to see if there's a way to do this with an analytical function or two but so far no luck.

Answer (score 0):

select days, count(distinct(user)) as user_count
from mytable
group by days;

Answer (score 0):

select 
days,
exact_count_distinct(user) as user_count
from
table
group@100 by
1
;